# Mongoose will not execute findById callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am beginning to lose my mind. Why won't this simple mongoose command work? I am writing a script to update items in the database due to a schema change, and for whatever reason I cannot get the actual update methods to work... Like at all. They don't error out or anything. They Just don't execute. Everything else in my script (that interacts with the db connection) is executing fine.

This is the jist of my code:

```js
const db = require('../../server/db');


async function itemMigration() {

  const items = await db.Items.find().exec();

  if (items) {
    items.forEach( async item => {
      console.log(item); // this works! It logs the item to my console.

      // this doesn't do anything.
      await db.Items.findById(item._id, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(item.type)
        doc.set(item);
        doc.save();
      })
    }
  }
}
```

What I expect this code to do is find all `items` in my DB, iterate over them, and then update each one. The first part works as expected. I get the items and I log each item to the console. The `findById()` part is what does not execute. I have tried it with/without the `await` command... makes no difference. I should be seeing logs to my console, but none appear ‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: This code worked for me, except I had to add a missing bracket to close the forEach() function after the 3rd to bottom curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

When awaiting for async function, callback functions shouln't be provided.

This is how your code should look like:

```
try {
    const doc = await db.Items.findById(item._id)
    doc.set(item);
    await doc.save();

} catch (error) {
    console.error(item.type)   
}
```

PS: remove `async` from `items.forEach( async item ...` 
  if you would like the items to be ecxuted in the right order just use the regular `for` and `await` in its body.

Comment: still not working. Nothing is getting past that initial `const doc = await db.Items.findById(item._id)` line.

Comment: it is honestly no different from what you wrote. I am starting to use the node debugger and like I thought nothing is getting by that one line. Is it possible the database connection is... finicky?

Comment: When debugging your code could you find out if item._id if is populated.